# Diagramming phrases of form “two miles from [something]”

Tags: grammar, diagramming, measure-phrases

How would you diagram “After the taxi dropped me off two miles from my apartment, I walked home”?

I’m mostly wondering about the phrase “two miles”—would it make more sense to think of it as modifying the verb “dropped” or the preposition “from”?

Comment: How would you diagram _After the taxi dropped me there, I walked home_?. Remove the _there_ and substitute the measure NP _two miles from my apartment_.

Comment: I'd say that your first suggestion is correct. The measure phrase "two miles from my apartment" is a locative adjunct in clause structure, i.e. it modifies the verb phrase "dropped me off".

Comment: @BillJ In In *The fireworks are two miles from my apartment* is the measure phrase now a complement rather than an adjunct? And if so, would that make it  an [adverbial complement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/539689/2085)?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/600100/2085).